# Chakra UI tooltips causing serious lag

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, lag, chakra-ui

I've been using Chakra UI in my React app and have noticed that the tooltips are causing some serious lag after being hovered over. I have a color palette with about 55 buttons, each with a tooltip, and after hovering over a button, the lag persists even when I hover off of it. This was really unexpected and took me about 4 hours to troubleshoot.

I'm using useMemo() in my code, and the buttons and tooltips never update after the first render. I'm guessing that this is a bug in Chakra UI, but I'm not sure what to do. Has anyone else experienced this issue or know what could be causing it? Any suggestions for how to work around it in the meantime? I'm considering just removing the tooltips, but I'd really like to find a solution if possible.

Here is my code for the ColorPreset component that contains the tooltips:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Tooltip } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "./ColorPreset.css";

function ColorPreset({ color, onClick }) {
  return (
    <Tooltip label={color} placement="top">
      <Button
        padding="20px"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: color,
        }}
        onClick={onClick}
      />
    </Tooltip>
  );
}

export default ColorPreset;
```

I'd really appreciate any help or guidance on this!